# Python: Change my Results

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def make_doctor(phrase):

     when_joined = "Dr."+phrase
     phrase = input ()
     return (when_joined)

Doctors_names = make_doctor("Hemsworth")

print (Doctors_names)
```

The result to this line of code come out as "Hemsworth" "Dr. Hemsworth". Is there a way to re-write the code where the result is just whatever is input? In this case "Hemsworth".

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. The title of your question is very vague, and your code is not formatted properly: this may explain the downvote you received

Comment: `return "Dr."+input()`, or if you want to keep your codelines, ask for input _first_ , then calculate the combination of your input and `"Dr."`, then return the combination.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the responses people. Patrick, Ian thank you. I'm new to stack overflow and coding so pardon my question structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
def make_doctor(phrase):
     when_joined = "Dr."+ phrase
     # this line is not needed #phrase = input ()
     return (when_joined)

Doctors_names = make_doctor("Hemsworth")

print (Doctors_names)
```

Your question is not clear. See the comments above.

Maybe it was this:

```
def make_doctor(phrase):
     when_joined = "Dr."+ phrase
     return (when_joined)

phrase = input ("Which name?")
Doctors_names = make_doctor(phrase)
print (Doctors_names)
```